# PySpark task exception handling

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a loop in a pyspark (Spark3 cluster) task like this :

```
def myfunc(rows):
  #Some dynamodb Table initiation stuff (nothing fancy)
  
  with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for row in rows():
      try:
        batch.put_item(..)
      except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "ProvisionedThroughputExceededException":
          #handle the issue here
```

And here is the call to this function from spark

```
    df.foreachPartition(lambda x : myfunc(x))
```

This code actually works fine. Sometime I receive the exception ProvisionedThroughputExceededException and it's handled. However something super weird is that, if the task handling the bunch of rows seems to encounter the exception it will end as a failing task eventhough the excpetion has been handled, as if spark task check some kind of historical exception to see if something bad happend during the processing:

Here the output from the task :

```
Getting An error occurred (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation ... ==> handling
Getting An error occurred (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation ... ==> handling
Getting An error occurred (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation ... ==> handling
2022-03-30 08:40:33,029 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 9)
```

and then it prints out the stack trace as follows

```
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
    process()
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 595, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 425, in func
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 874, in func
  File "6.YL_flow_2-ecf3d86.py", line 136, in <lambda>
  File "6.YL_flow_2-ecf3d86.py", line 98, in greedy_dyn_send
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000004/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 156, in __exit__
    self._flush()
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000004/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 137, in _flush
    RequestItems={self._table_name: items_to_send})
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000004/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 388, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/srv/ssd2/yarn/nm/usercache/svc_df_omni/appcache/application_1648119616278_365920/container_e298_1648119616278_365920_01_000004/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 708, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: An error occurred (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation (reached max retries: 1): The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1004)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2154)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-03-30 08:40:33,089 INFO YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 73
```

So I was wondering how spark handle "finishing" a task. Will it say that the task is failed if we encounter an exception and handled it ? Should we clean something whenever we handle an exception ?